# Should I clean plastic fermenters wth PBW

Tags: cleaning

I'm concerned about cleaning my fermenter with PBW.  The crystals seem hard & sharp and take a while to dissolve. I don't want to scratch the bucket. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you do not begin abrasive scrubbing until the PBW crystals are dissolved, PBW should not be a problem.

Let me differentiate between HDPE plastic bucket fermenters and PET carboys (like Better Bottle).

I find that I don't need anything other than hot tap water, a soft sponge, and a slight amount of elbow grease to clean HDPE bucket fermenters. Exposure to PBW for a short time shouldn't hurt.

But it is not recommended to use PBW or Oxy-based cleaners for PET carboys because it causes stress corrosion, and eventually will lead to clouding or failure of the PET carboy.

Better Bottle recommends using Free & Clear Natural 2X Seventh Generation detergent, an enzyme based cleaner in [this study of the effects of various cleansers](http://www.better-bottle.com/pdf/WashingSanitizingStudy.pdf). What works for me is adding a small amount of hot tap water, a small amount of cleanser, and a washcloth, and rolling the carboy on the counter or floor. The washcloth rubs off all of the krausen rings.

Edit: it is **not** recommended to use PBW or Oxy on PET.

Comment: I assume you mean it is NOT recommend for PET carboys?

Comment: I fixed the error above.

Comment: Although this research does not mention sodium percarbonate directly, it does say "limited resistance to hot water andwashing soda (sodium carbonate)." http://www.scribd.com/doc/104244759/Corrosion-of-Polymers-and-Elastomers-Corrosion-Engineering-Handbook-Second-Edition#page=116

Comment: My experience with plastic water bottles (that probably are PET) is that very hot water and OxiClean over night will sometimes cause a crack to form, making the bottle useless.

Answer (score 1):

No, dissolved/dissolving PBW will not scratch your plastic fermenters.

Answer (score 0):

I do just with room temp water, my blichmann boil kettle I usually get the water around 140-160F